# Probability of an event occurring if two other events do

Tags: probability

I know very little probability, but there is a relatively simple problem I cannot solve with by Googling. The problem is: If I know that when A is true, event C has P<sub>1</sub> chance of occurring, and when B is true, event C has P<sub>2</sub> chance of occurring, then what is the probability that event C occurs when A and B are true, assuming A and B are independent?

A link to a relevant article or explanation would be acceptable

The specific problem this is being applied to is:
I know if a the name of a company has a given word in it (A is whether the company has the word in its name), it has a P<sub>1</sub> probability of being in a given sector (event C occurring). I also know if it has another word in its name (B) then it has P<sub>2</sub> probability of being in the sector. I want to know what the probability of the company being in the sector is if it contains both words.

Note: I don't actually know what sector the company is, or anything about it but its name

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough information to determine that.

As a concrete example, suppose you flip a coin twice, and $A$ means "heads in the first flip" and $B$ means "heads in the second flip". (These are certainly independent).

You're then told that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are both $1/2$. But this can be either because $C$ means "tails at least once" (or "different flips"), or because $C$ means "heads both times", in which case your sought-for probability is either $0$ or $1$, respectively.

Comment: This is the OP, I'm just having account issues. Anyway, I'm encountering this problem in a software environment, and there is more information. If I give a more complete version of the problem, might there be a solution?

Comment: The specific problem this is being applied to is: I know if a the name of a company has a given word in it (A is whether the company has the word in its name), it has a P1 probability of being in a given sector (event C occurring). I also know if it has another word in its name (B) then it has P2 probability of being in the sector. I want to know what the probability of the company being in the sector is if it contains both words.

Note: I don't actually know what sector the company is, or anything about it but its name

Comment: @Fractaly: Nope, insufficient data.